# Pandas dataframes...iterations vs list comprehensions...advice sought

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm a newcomer to Python and I'm trying to get some advice, please.

I'm interrogating a CSV file with about 500k rows of data.

I'm (kinda) trying to replicate the logic of an xlsx SUMIFS formula with multiple criteria to create a new dataframe out of my initial data set using groupby().

I think this works well for me (although do tell me if this is dumb) since I want my output in the form of a matrix (it's 132 rows x 15 columns).  I can then multiply it by other matrices with the same dimensions and then export to excel.

On this approach, there's about 100 different versions I need to do...one of the criteria / variables in the dataframe pertains to 'COUNTRY'...and I have a list of 100 countries that I need to do the analysis for.

```
df = pd.read_csv("SourceFile.csv", encoding = 'latin-1')
df = df[((df.Item == cat | (df.Item == dog) | (df.Item == sheep) | (df.Item == chihuahua))
         & (df.Year == 2019)
         & (df.Country == 0) <<< This is the variable I want to repeat 100x
         ].groupby(['ID', 'Customer'])['Amount'].sum().unstack(fill_value = 0)
```

Before I start figuring out how to loop through my list of country codes my questions are:

(1) Is this a sensible way of structuring the analysis? I fear I am trying too hard to make Python behave like Excel rather than using Python in the most efficient way possible

(2) Lots of what I have read suggests that list comprehension (or vectorisation) is going to be faster than using a for-loop...is that relevant in this instance?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is possible use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) instead multiple `|`, then pass `Country` to `groupby` and last parse output by `Country` level of `MultiIndex`:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
L = ['cat','dog','sheep','chihuahua','pig','goat']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item':np.random.choice(L, size=20),
                   'Country':[0] * 10 + [1] * 10,
                   'ID':np.random.choice(['id1','id2','id3'], size=20),
                   'Year':2019,
                   'Amount':np.random.randint(20, size=20),
                   'Customer':np.random.choice(['cust1','cust2','cust3','cust4'], size=20)})
print (df)
         Item  Country   ID  Year  Amount Customer
0         cat        0  id1  2019      14    cust2
1         cat        0  id1  2019       4    cust3
2   chihuahua        0  id1  2019       2    cust4
3   chihuahua        0  id3  2019       3    cust4
4   chihuahua        0  id1  2019       1    cust3
5        goat        0  id2  2019       9    cust1
6   chihuahua        0  id2  2019      19    cust1
7         cat        0  id2  2019      18    cust4
8        goat        0  id3  2019      16    cust3
9         cat        0  id2  2019       1    cust1
10        cat        1  id3  2019      10    cust3
11        cat        1  id2  2019       2    cust3
12      sheep        1  id2  2019       1    cust3
13        dog        1  id3  2019      16    cust1
14  chihuahua        1  id3  2019      18    cust3
15  chihuahua        1  id3  2019       8    cust3
16      sheep        1  id3  2019      14    cust2
17  chihuahua        1  id2  2019       8    cust1
18       goat        1  id1  2019      14    cust4
19        cat        1  id3  2019      11    cust2
```

---

```
df1 = (df[df.Item.isin(['cat','dog','sheep','chihuahua']) & (df.Year == 2019)]
             .groupby(['Country','ID', 'Customer'])['Amount']
             .sum()
             .unstack(fill_value = 0))

print (df1)
Customer     cust1  cust2  cust3  cust4
Country ID                             
0       id1      0     14      5      2
        id2     20      0      0     18
        id3      0      0      0      3
1       id2      8      0      3      0
        id3     16     25     36      0
```

---

```
print (df1.loc[0])
Customer  cust1  cust2  cust3  cust4
ID                                  
id1           0     14      5      2
id2          20      0      0     18
id3           0      0      0      3
```

Comment: Thank you - that is (a) helpful and (b) really clever!  I will play around with the MultiIndex functionality. Quick follow-up, please...in df1 = (df[.......))...what are the first set of parentheses doing? If I change the indentation on groupby / sum / unstack the code will run without those parentheses...but I'm trying to figure out what they are doing. Thanks!

Comment: One (final) follow-up...what are the merits of using 'loc[] here rather than .xs(). For a newbie, it seems like .xs() gives me slightly better auditability because I have to stipulate more things. Am I losing anything in functionality terms using .xs() to filter within a multindex vs .loc[]? Thanks

Comment: @harrison10001 - yes, `.xs` is more flexible if working with Multiindex, if first level like in data above `loc` also working nice.